# awakeFromNib from nib1 got called when programmatically load nib2

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xib, nib

When I loaded nib2 from nib1 with the syntax below, the awakeFromNib method from my current nib (nib1) got called again. (But not the initWithFrame method)  Even though the nib2 was opened and got the focus correctly.  I do not want the awakeFromNib from the nib1 to be executed again.  What do I miss?

```
[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"iQueryWindow" owner:self];
```

More info:  iQueryWindow.xib has a iQueryView.h and iQueryView.m subclass of NSView  associated with it to create the window view with button, textfield, etc.  The sequence of event looked like this:  I clicked a button from nib1 view, its clicked event only has a single line of code as above to open nib2's window.  Nib2's window opened with all initialization including inintWithFrame and awakeFromNib methods of its (nib2) own.  After that I can observed that nib1's window changed due to its own awakeFromNib got called (I can also observed this via the Console with the help of NSlog statement).  (nib2's window displayed on top of nib1's.)  There is a button on nib2 that will close nib2 with this: [self.window close].

Comment: Can you please show more code? What you've provided isn't enough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Since you have the current view as the owner, it will receive the awakeFromNib. What do you soon after loading?

Comment: @joshpaul: On the nib1, I clicked on a button.  The button_clicked event only has a single line of code above to open nib2.  Nib1's window was still on the screen.  Nib2's window just displayed on top of nib1's.  I can tell that awakeFromNib from nib1 was being called because the info on the screen of nib1 changed and from looking into the Console monitor.  The sequence of event looked like this after the call to open nib2:  Nib2 got open, then awakeFromNib from nib2 got called.

Comment: @Deepak: After nib2 opened, I can use it as normal window... accessing all buttons, etc. and carrying out the intended tasks.  There is a button on nib2 that when clicked, it will close nib2.  And I am back to nib1.  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-awakeFromNib` is sent to all objects in the nib file, including the file’s owner. If you have an object that’s loaded from a nib file and make that object the owner of another nib file, it’ll receive `-awakeFromNib` twice. This happens by design.

Although you could have an ivar to manage the state of your class with regard to awakening from nib, consider using a subclass of `NSViewController` (or `NSWindowController`; it’s not really clear whether the nib2 has a view or a window as one of its top-level objects) as the file’s owner of the secondary nib file.

Comment: 1.  nib2 has a window (NSWindow) as its top-level object.  the iQueryView subclass of NSView is inside this window.
2.  I did not set file's owner of the nib2 - there is none.

Comment: @user `[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"iQueryWindow" owner:self];` means that the owner is `self`, which I assume is an object loaded from nib1.

Comment: I used NSWindowController instead of NSBundle to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Per Bavarious suggestion, I use NSWindowController instead of NSBundle to resolve this issue.  Here is the code:

```
NSWindowController *iQWController = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"iQueryWindow"];
[iQWController showWindow:sender];
```